# PHP Laravel Ruta STORE no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, rutas, crud

Estoy comenzando con un proyecto Laravel. Me encuentro haciendo un simple CRUD de una tabla llamada EmpPelu, pero cuando hago submit del formulario con los datos a cargar, la ruta parece nunca llamar a la función "store" de mi controlador.

Al momento de hacer submit del formulario de la vista, el la URL es redirigida hacia la ruta "EmpPelu/store"; sin embargo, aunque la ruta está definida en el archivo web.php y aunque está creado el metodo "store" en el controlador, el sitio responde con ERROR 419 - PAGE EXPIRED

vista (create.blade.php)

```
<html lang="en">
   <body>
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Nuevo Empleado</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <form method="post" action="store">
                <p>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="EmpPeluApell" placeholder="Apellido" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                        <input type="text" name="EmpPeluNomb" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                        <input type="text" name="EmpPeluObserv" placeholder="Observaciones" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success">
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
</html>
```

Archivo web.php:

```
<?php
Route::post('EmpPelu/store','EmpPeluController@store');
Route::post('EmpPelu/create','EmpPeluController@create');
Route::post('EmpPelu/update{EmpPeluCod}','EmpPeluController@update');
Route::get('EmpPelu/destroy{EmpPeluCod}','EmpPeluController@destroy');

Route::resource('EmpPelu','EmpPeluController');
?>
```

controlador (EmpPeluController.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\EmpPelu;
use View;

class EmpPeluController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $empleados = EmpPelu::orderBy('EmpPeluApell','DESC')->get();

        return view('CRUDS.EmpPelu.index',compact('empleados'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
         return View::make('CRUDS.EmpPelu.create');
    }


    public function store()
    {


        $empleado = new EmpPelu;
        $empleado->EmpPeluApell     = Input::get('EmpPeluApell');
        $empleado->EmpPeluNomb      = Input::get('EmpPeluNomb');
        $empleado->EmpPeluObserv    = Input::get('EmpPeluObserv');

        if($emplead->save()){
            Session::flash('message','Guardado correctamente!');
            Session::flash('class','success');
        }else{
            Session::flash('message','Ha ocurrido un errr!');
            Session::flash('class','danger');
        }

         return View::make('CRUDS.EmpPelu.create');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Alguna idea?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que definas un formulario HTML en tu aplicación, debes incluir un campo de token [@csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf) oculto en el formulario para que el middleware de protección CSRF pueda validar la solicitud.

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Con Blade:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
  @csrf
  ...
```

---

Además...

> Los formularios HTML no admiten las acciones PUT, PATCH o DELETE. Por
>   lo tanto, cuando se define las rutas PUT, PATCH o DELETE que se llaman desde
>   un formulario HTML, se debe agregar un campo [@method()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing) al
>   formulario. El valor enviado con el campo `_method` se utilizará como
>   método de solicitud HTTP:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```

Con Blade:

```
form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
  @method('PUT')
  @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Entendido y está solucionado con algo similar a lo que me explicas. El formulario es de tipo POST, por lo que agregando al mismo @method('POST') y @csrf llego al método correctamente.
Gracias!

Comment: Me alegro... solo informarte que si es `POST` o `GET` no tienes que poner `@method('POST')` esto es solo para los `PUT, PATCH o DELETE`

Comment: Vale, era simplemente el @csrf lo que me faltaba. Gracias!!